# Irreducibles in polynomial rings

Tags: polynomials

Let R be a reduced ring with characteristic zero which is not an integral domain. Is "x" necessarily non irreducible in R[x]?

Answer (score 4):

Let $R:=\frac{K[Y]}{(Y)}\times\frac{K[Y]}{(Y+1)}\cong\frac{K[Y]}{(Y(Y+1))}$, $e:=(\overline{1},0)$, and $f:=1-e=(0,\overline{1})$. Since $e$ is idempotent, and $ef=0$, in $R[X]$ we have: $(e+fX)(f+eX)=X$, thus $X$ is not irreducible; but $R$ is reduced, with characteristic zero if we take $K=\mathbb{Q}$.

Answer (score 2):

For $R=k[u,v]/(uv)$, $x$ is irreducible in $R[x]$. Suppose $x=A(x)B(x)$, with $A(x)=a_0+a_1x+\ldots $, $B(x)=b_0+b_1x+\ldots $. One must have $a_0\in (u)$, $b_0\in (v)$  (or the other way around). But then the coefficient of $x$ in $A(x)B(x)$ belongs to the ideal $(u,v)$, a contradiction.